# How to add value to a list dynamically in android?

Tags: java, android, list, listview, arraylist

I have a list in which i can assigned the values statically.

```
    private List<ListData> mDataList = Arrays.asList(
        new ListData("Arun"),
        new ListData("Jega"),
        new ListData("Kabilan"),
        new ListData("Karthick"),
        new ListData("Joushva"),
        new ListData("Niranjana"),
        new ListData("Paramesh"),
        new ListData("Prabha"),new ListData("Test1"),new ListData("Test2")   );
```

The problem is now i got a scenario where i should get these value dynamically from web apim and i have to set it to the List variable mDataList.
Please help me to clear this. Thanks in advance.
Here is my complete code.

```
     public class ReportFragment extends Fragment {
View ParentView;
private static final int HIGHLIGHT_COLOR = 0x999be6ff;

// list of data items
private List<ListData> mDataList = Arrays.asList(
        new ListData("Arun"),
        new ListData("Jega"),
        new ListData("Kabilan"),
        new ListData("Karthick"),
        new ListData("Joushva"),
        new ListData("Niranjana"),
        new ListData("Paramesh"),
        new ListData("Prabha"),new ListData("Test1"),new ListData("Test2")

);
// declare the color generator and drawable builder
private ColorGenerator mColorGenerator = ColorGenerator.MATERIAL;
private TextDrawable.IBuilder mDrawableBuilder;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ParentView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.report_fragment, container, false);
    init();
    return  ParentView;
}
public void init(){
    mDrawableBuilder = TextDrawable.builder()
            .round();
    // init the list view and its adapter
   final ListView listView = (ListView) ParentView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    listView.setAdapter(new SampleAdapter());
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {


        }

    });
}
private class SampleAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mDataList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public ListData getItem(int position) {
        return mDataList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = View.inflate(getActivity() , R.layout.list_item_layout, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        ListData item = getItem(position);

        // provide support for selected state
        updateCheckedState(holder, item);
        holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // when the image is clicked, update the selected state
                ListData data = getItem(position);
                data.setChecked(!data.isChecked);
                updateCheckedState(holder, data);
            }
        });
        holder.textView.setText(item.data);

        return convertView;
    }

    private void updateCheckedState(ViewHolder holder, ListData item) {
        if (item.isChecked) {
            holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(mDrawableBuilder.build(" ", 0xff616161));
            holder.view.setBackgroundColor(HIGHLIGHT_COLOR);
            holder.checkIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else {
            TextDrawable drawable = mDrawableBuilder.build(String.valueOf(item.data.charAt(0)), mColorGenerator.getColor(item.data));
            holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
            holder.view.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            holder.checkIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
}

private static class ViewHolder {

    private View view;

    private ImageView imageView;

    private TextView textView;

    private ImageView checkIcon;

    private ViewHolder(View view) {
        this.view = view;
        imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        checkIcon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.check_icon);
    }
}

private static class ListData {

    private String data;

    private boolean isChecked;

    public ListData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void setChecked(boolean isChecked) {
        this.isChecked = isChecked;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: 1. add data to your list. 2. call notifyDataSetChange on your listview object. 3.????? 4. Profit

Comment: I have tried like this ,even knowing tat  this is not the right way to do. public void addList(String[] a){
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
            mDataList = Arrays.asList(
                    new ListData(a[i]));
        }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a method to add items in your adapter class, this method will add item to 
itemlist. this will add items dynamically on your list or grid.
e.g

```
public void addItem(Item item){
      itemList.add(item);
     notifydatasetchanged();}
```

Comment: will you please give me an elaborate answer for this?\

Answer (score 0):

create a adapter class and constructor, in constructor just initialize the item arraylist and create extra method called addItem() this method will add item to your arraylist. after that you just have to call notifyDatasetchanged  and your new item will be added.